# dimple js what if there is no data returned after using dimple.filterData()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm trying to draw a chart using dimple JS.. I need to filter the data on selecting a drop down. I'm getting an error when there is NO data returned when I'm using dimple.filterData(....). Please let me know how to deal with this when no data is returned by dimple.filterData() function.

I want to display "No Data for the current selection" when no data is returned.

[JS Fiddle Link Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeeptinku/0zxz7mf2/)

```
<select id="Time">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Year">YTD</option>
<option value="Month">MTD</option>
<option value="Week">WTD</option>
```

$("#Time").on('change',function(){

```
$("#chartContainer").html('');
drawChart($(this).prop('id'), $(this).val());
```

});

function drawChart(id, value){

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var data = [
    { Time: "Year", Value: 1 },
    { Time: "Month", Value: 2 },
    { Time: "Month", Value: 3 }
];
data = dimple.filterData(data, id, value);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Time");
x.addOrderRule(["Year", "Month", "Week"]);
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.draw();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dimple.filterData(...)` call returns an empty array when there is no matching data. Just check to see if the array is empty:

```
 data = dimple.filterData(data, id, value);
 if(data.length > 0) {
   // Charting code here...   
 } else { 
   alert("No data for the current selection");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so mcuh for the answer!! :)  before asking this question, I tried using if(data){ //charting code.. } it was showing some error.. And It's working now with your answer ..